# Fill density curves with transparent color

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density, density-plot

I have a data frame and want to do a overlay density plot based on the two columns. I want the colors to be transparent. I have done this using the fill option and basically assigning fill to be a factor column. When you have a factor column by default all the fills going to be transparent.

But in a situation like this where there are no factors how do we fill it with transparent.

```
library("ggplot2")
vec1 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(2000, 0, 1))
vec2 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(3000, 1, 1.5))

ggplot() + geom_density(aes(x=x), fill="red", data=vec1) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=x), fill="blue", data=vec2)
```

I tried adding `geom_density(alpha=0.4)` but it didn't do any good.
[image]

Comment: Put `alpha=.4` inside the call to `geom_density(...)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
ggplot() + geom_density(aes(x=x), fill="red", data=vec1, alpha=.5) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=x), fill="blue", data=vec2, alpha=.5)
```

**EDIT** Response to OPs comment.

This is the idiomatic way to plot multiple curves with `ggplot`.

```
gg <- rbind(vec1,vec2)
gg$group <- factor(rep(1:2,c(2000,3000)))
ggplot(gg, aes(x=x, fill=group)) + 
  geom_density(alpha=.5)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue"))
```

[image]

So we first bind the two datasets together, then add a grouping variable. Then we tell `ggplot` which is the grouping variable and it takes care of everything else.

Comment: Is there a good way to label this density plots, I plan to plot more than two on top of each other

Comment: only issue here is data that i am plotting is in same row for example above density graphs would come from 001, 200, 100, -- 200 and 100 are columns are the density functions that case assigning group is hard.

Comment: Yes but your example is not like that. Read the documentation on `melt(...)` in the `reshape2` package. This is the way to convert from "wide" format - groups in different columns, to "long" format - all data in one column with the groups distinguished by a second column.

Comment: Can you adapt the code to apply the transparency only to front density? I am trying to replicate Figure 4 from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.07072.pdf) (page. 27).